# PATINDEX vs LEN performance MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Which of these two functions will have better performance to find the length of the input string?

```
PATINDEX ('%%{terminator}%%',inputString)
```

or

```
LEN(inputString)
```

Comment: What does your sample data look like?

Comment: LEN should be faster, but why not just measure it yourself?

Comment: @Ryan: the data sample is a comma separated list of names.

Comment: @Jasmine: The execution time isnt large enough to see with the sample data set I have(MS Studio shows it as 00:00:00)..I am assuming LEN to be faster bt want to make sure.

Comment: Micro-optimization is the devil

Comment: I have to believe `LEN` would be faster because it doesn't have to do any comparison logic. I have no idea how LEN works, but I would guess for Varchar and Nvarchar it simply looks at the storage size and infers the size. For PATINDEX I believe it has to analyze the contents of the data which seems like it would inherently take longer. Just my 2 cent guess.

Comment: @Love2Learn - `LEN` also looks at the data as it disregards trailing spaces.

Comment: @MartinSmith Good to know. I still have to imagine it would be faster because it only has to look from the end of the string back until it finds a non-space character (I just checked and preceding spaces are included) so at least it would be an optimized data comparison, right? If you don't care about trailing spaces OR if you want them considered you could use `DataLength`, this would have to be fastest, yeah?

Comment: @Love2Learn - Yes I'm pretty sure that `LEN` will do less work than `PATINDEX`. For large object types using `DataLength` can be faster than `LEN` IIRC

Comment: SQL Server optimization is done with indexes. The two functions you show do different things, is apples to oranges. `LEN` of a string will always be faster than any function that require to access the string content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The length of a string in sql server is often stored separately from the text. You don't have to walk the string to know how long it is. It's just a lookup, or a lookup followed by walking from the *end* of the string (to check trailing spaces), rather than the beginning. Assuming you were able to construct a PATINDEX to return the last index of the string, that would still require you to walk the string to evaluate the length. I suppose you could construct a scenario where PATINDEX was faster, but only if you have strings that consist mostly of trailing space.

So LEN() wins here in any way you can think of: semantics (best communicates meaning of what you're doing), correctness (getting the PATINDEX right would be tricky), and performance.